# How to control a stepper motor using Infrared IR Receiver?

Tags: arduino

Hi im new to Arduino Uno

My question is how to turn a stepper motor 90 dgree clockwise only when the infrared censored a something and turn anti-clockwise when the second infrared censored something is pressed again?

Stepper motor
Infrared transmitter/receiver pair

your help will be much appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Software and hardware my friend, software and hardware.

First, you'll need to connect your sensors to the Arduino and make sure you can read them reliably. You can write a sketch that outputs the values to the serial port and monitor them on your computer.

Second, you'll need to connect your motor. A stepper motor is going to need a driver, such as the "Adafruit Motor/Stepper/Servo Shield for Arduino v2 Kit" ([link](http://www.adafruit.com/products/81)). This kit has sample code you can use to figure out how to drive the motor.

Then you'd connect these two independent pieces together. Write logic that puts the motor in one position when your sensor is sensing, and another when it's not, or use your second sensor to make the second motion.

Note: Stepper motors and the drivers are expensive and maybe not what you really want. For one thing, they use relative motion, not absolute position. If they miss steps (due to hitting something or being manually moved) then they remain in the wrong position until you fix them.

A cheaper and perhaps better solution is to use a [hobby servo](http://www.adafruit.com/products/169). They are cheap and use absolute positioning, which means that when you tell them to go somewhere they will always try to get to that position. Also, you can drive them directly from the Arduino without a driver board. One of the built-in Arduino sketches shows how to run them.